# Firemonkey equivalent to ActionList?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Just started exploring the surface of Firemonkey in Delphi XE2.  I've noticed that it has no TActionList component, and none of the components have an Action property (except for TButton, strangely).

Is there a new and better way for managing actions in Firemonkey?

Comment: FireMonkey is currently preview technology. Expect it to be mature in 2 years time. Building real apps now is going to be very challenging and will leave a significant legacy.

Comment: @David: It is not preview technology. You may see it as such, but it certainly isn't meant to be or advertised as preview.

Comment: @rudy It's clearly not fully fledged. Doesn't matter what the advertising is. What matters is how it is.

Comment: @David: it is a 1.0 release. But it is not a preview.

Comment: @Rudy It's a stroke of genius releasing it in its current state, early in its gestation. Much better than polishing for 2 years and then releasing. I applaud them for doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I have seen. I would speculate that TActionList did not make the feature list for the first release of Firemonkey. This is not at all surprising given the number of new features introduced in XE2.

Comment: There is no support for TAction and TActionList in the current FireMonkey version. As Rudy mentioned it is a 1.0 release, and we have already seen a few posts in the embarcadero forums that it will get updated quickly.